# Is the circuit unitary in Nielsen's method for calculating complexity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I was trying to learn how to calculate circuit complexity ([1707.08570](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.08570)) when I chanced upon a seemingly confusing concept. The "Nielsen method" involves looking at a unitary transformation $U$ that takes a reference state $\Psi^R$ to a target state $\Psi^T$:
$$|\Psi^T(t)\rangle=U(t)|\Psi^R(0)\rangle$$
The idea is to rewrite $U$ as an optimized circuit of fundamental quantum gates, and finding the cost associated with this circuit. Examples of these gates include :
\begin{aligned}
H \psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) &=e^{i \epsilon p_{0} x_{0}} \psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) & & \text { (global) phase change } \\
J_{1} \psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) &=\psi\left(x_{1}+\epsilon x_{0}, x_{2}\right) & & \text { shift } x_{1} \text { by constant } \epsilon x_{0} \\
K_{1} \psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) &=e^{i \epsilon p_{0} x_{1}} \psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) & & \text { shift } p_{1} \text { by constant } \epsilon p_{0} \\
Q_{21} \psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) &=\psi\left(x_{1}+\epsilon x_{2}, x_{2}\right) & & \text { shift } x_{1} \text { by } \epsilon x_{2} \quad \text { (entangling gate) } \\
Q_{11} \psi\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right) &=e^{\epsilon / 2} \psi\left(e^{\epsilon} x_{1}, x_{2}\right) & & \text { scale } x_{1} \rightarrow e^{\epsilon} x_{1} \quad \text { (scaling gate) }
\end{aligned}
where $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal parameter.  In ([1810.02734](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.02734)), this procedure leads to the following form of $U$ (Eq 3.38):
$$U(\tau)=\exp \left(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \alpha^{k}(\tau) M_{k}^{\text {diag }}\right)$$
where $\{\alpha^k\}$ are complex (and not infinitesimal) and $\{M_k\}$ are diagonal matrices with an identity in the $k^{th}$ position (rest are zero). How can I show that $U$ is indeed unitary as per the original assumption?

Edit : There was a dubious error in the question as was pointed out by @Jahan Claes, regarding unitarity of the gate $Q_{aa}$. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I think it might be unitary? How do you know it isn't unitary?

Comment: Q does not satisfy  Q^{\dagger}Q=I unless \epsilon is strictly zero. Also in the final expression for U, \alpha_k are calculated to have real parts which are non zero and finite. U then would also not satisfy U^{\dagger}U=I.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compute $Q_{aa}^\dagger Q_{aa}$. For the rest of this post, I'll drop the $a$ subscript for convenience. Remember that $[x,p]=i$, so that we have $px=xp-i$.

We have:
\begin{align}
Q^\dagger Q & = e^{\epsilon}(e^{i\epsilon xp})^\dagger e^{i\epsilon xp}\\
& = e^{\epsilon}e^{-i\epsilon px}e^{i\epsilon xp}\\
&= e^\epsilon e^{-i\epsilon(xp-i)}e^{i\epsilon xp}\\
&= e^\epsilon e^{-\epsilon}e^{-i\epsilon xp}e^{i\epsilon xp}\\
&=1
\end{align}

So $Q$ is indeed unitary!

Comment: Ah okay, my bad, you're right about $Q$!. But its not obvious to me how to show the same for $U$ in the final expression given in the question, as a consistency check.

Comment: @ImpostorSyndrome If the decomposition is as described, the matrix isn't unitary without other constraints on $\alpha$, such as $|\alpha|=1$. Just because you can get a unitary into a certain form doesn't mean that ALL matrices of that form are unitary.